# How to detect google enterprise account?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, gmail-api

Google enterprise accounts does not have the common domain "gmail", example *tom@miracle.com*, *hela@bran.com*. So there is no way of telling if an account is a google enterprise account or from a different email provider just by looking at it.
Is there any api provided by google of knowing if the account (say *tom@miracle.com*) is a google account or not

Comment: Probably the MX record in DNS will reveal what you are asking, though without real-world examples, hard to test. (Probably don't invent email addresses which could belong to real people; you will cause them to receive more spam.)

Comment: @triplee Thanks. MX records tell me exactly what I need

Answer (score 0):

We can detect if the account belongs to google or any other enterprise by doing a simple DNS look up of the MX data.
One such example is
GET:   `https://dns.google/resolve?name=miracle.com&type=MX`

Comment: You can run `dig` or `host` or `nslookup` locally too. The last one is the least useful and convenient, so predictably that's what you get on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can't tell from an email address: `bob@example.com` could be a [consumer account](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/identity/overview-google-authentication#consumer_account), a [managed user account](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/identity/overview-google-authentication#managed_user_account), or even both (if it's a conflicting account).

Once the user has authenticated, you can identify managed user accounts by [checking the `hd` claim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68453919/signing-in-with-google-only-allowing-organizational-domains-accounts/68485026#68485026).